# Compare Multiple DataFrames Add New Column Fill With Binary Values For Matches

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, match

Let's say I have 2 dataframes. One with merged dataframe of all instances and another with only unique instances of column id.

df1 looks something like this:

```
|    id    |    category_name
|  459291  |    c1
|  349532  |    c1
|  459291  |    c2
|  719300  |    c1
|  349532  |    c3
|  459291  |    c4
|  649202  |    c2
|  459291  |    c5
```

df2 looks something like this:

```
|    id    |    category_name
|  459291  |    c1
|  349532  |    c1
|  719300  |    c1
|  649202  |    c2
```

What I want to do is create new columns on df2 for each value in column 'category_name' and output a 1 or 0 if unique value in 'id' has that matching 'category_name'. I would then drop the column 'category_name'. So, my expected output I'm looking for would be something like this

```
|    id    |    c1                |     c2          |     c3        |  c4 |
|  459291  |           1          |        1        |        1      |     1    |
|  349532  |           1          |        1        |        0      |     0    |
|  719300  |           1          |        0        |        0      |     0    |
|  649202  |           0          |        1        |        0      |     0    |
```

I feel like this could possibly be done using just the merged dataframe as well, but I'm not sure how I would drop the duplicates while keeping the new column values for each unique ID. any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `pandas.crosstab`

Comment: thank you i already figured this out a while back! appreciate your answer. please take a look at my recent bigquery question if you have any sql experience :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a way to do it with `pivot_table()` for a reason I can't get around not having to add the `aux` column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[459291,349532,459291,719300,349532,459291,649202,459291],
                   'playlist':['new','new','top','new','top','old','top','workout']})
df['aux'] = 1
new_df = pd.pivot_table(df,index='id',columns=['playlist'],aggfunc='count',values='aux').fillna(0).astype(int)
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
playlist  new  old  top  workout
id                              
349532      1    0    1        0
459291      1    1    1        1
649202      0    0    1        0
719300      1    0    0        0
```

Comment: this is perfect. thank you so much for this, didn't realize you could do a pivot table function in python. I'm definitely going to look more indepth and learn more about all of the pandas functionalities!

Comment: You have pretty much everything! Make sure to check these functions `groupby`, `sort_values()`, `pivot_table`, `melt()`, `crosstab` all really powerful!

Comment: appreciate your help! I have one more question. Let's say I have other columns besides ID and the playlist. How would I preserve them in the dataframe output while also performing the pivot table?

Comment: That would require some extra information, because as you can see we aggregating the `ID`  column, we should know what do we want to do with these extra columns (sum them per id? count them per id?) feel free to open a new question if you are having trouble with something different, or if it's just theoretical and we can discuss here.